# how to get only date part from the date time value in javascript

Tags: angularjs

i want to show only date value in the web page. im getting value like this

```
2019-05-24T10:42:42.6899084
```

javascript code

```
 $scope.date = $scope.myWelcome.updatedDate;
```

sample data in sql server

```
    UpdatedDate
    2019-05-24 10:27:01.6972592
```

Json Response

```
{"id":8,"updatedDate":"2019-05-24T12:48:25.3853657"}
```

Exp OP -

```
24-05-2019
```

HTML

```
<h3>{{ date.date |  date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</h3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) of angularjs.

```
{{ data.updatedDate |  date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/bgJQZnpbp5YOYlONxgO6?p=preview)**

Comment: @krishnamohan it is working, you should see 24/05/2019 below hello world text.

Comment: @krishnamohan for me i can able see 24/05/2019 under hello world text

Comment: @krishnamohan You do not need the demo anyway, just use the code above.

Comment: <h3>{{ data.updatedDate |  date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</h3> not working, getting error

Comment: @krishnamohan can you also write details of the error that you are getting please.

Comment: its not showing any error , but not displaying anything , it just showing blank

Comment: @krishnamohan it is because you have $scope.date in controller but in template you are using $scope.data, notice the difference between the last letters

Comment: i got it ,   <h3>{{ updDate |  date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</h3>. its working for me

Answer (score 2):

you can use slice(0, 10)

$scope.date = $scope.myWelcome.updatedDate.slice(0, 10);

//output

2019-05-24

```js
var d = {"id":8,"updatedDate":"2019-05-24T12:48:25.3853657"}

var a = d.updatedDate.slice(0, 10);

console.log(a);
```